# Variance of Max of random variable and constant

Tags: random-variables, maxima-minima, variance

I am looking for the variance of the max. function of a normally distributed random variable $X$ and a constant $c$. So trying to find $\operatorname{Var}\,[\max(X,c)]$ with $c>0$. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using the identity $\max (X,c)=\frac{1}{2}\left(X+c+|X-c|\right)$ might help.

Comment: I don't think you can actually calculate this analytically similarly to $P(X>c)$. Unless you accept the error function as good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StanTendijck! How would the error function help in this case, assuming it is accepted as good enough?

Comment: For ease of calculations, we'll take $X\sim N(0,1)$. Now to calculate the variance, you for example need to calculate $$ E[\max(X,c)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \max(x,c) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\,d x= \frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{c}  e^{-x^2/2}\,dx + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 
 \int_{c}^{\infty} x\cdot e^{-x^2/2}\,d x. $$ The last integral is easy (make a substitution of $y=x^2$) but the first integral is something that we cannot compute analytically and that's why the error function is introduced. Its definition is similar to the integral you need.